# Time Series Marginal Distribution Function Notation

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, time-series

Given am observed collection of *n* $\in Z^+$ random variables at arbitrary time points $ t_1,t_2,...,t_n$, a time series is defined by the joint distribution function $$F_{t_1,t_2,...,t_n}(c_1, c_2,...,c_n) = P(x_{t_1}\le c_1,x_{t_2}\le c_2,...,x_{t_n}\le c_n) $$

The text then goes on to define the marginal distribution functions to be $$F_t(x) = P\{x_t\le x
\}$$

and the corresponding marginal density functions as $$f_t(x) = \frac{\partial F_t(x)}{\partial x} $$

Can someone please explain the intuition behind the marginal distribution function(s) and the marginal density function(s) and perhaps provide some sort of a brief derivation of the relationship between the two? The notation is tripping me up.

Comment: Is this your first time working with joint probability distributions? (I ask this, because your question is not really about time series at all, but about the definitions of "marginal distribution," "distribution function," and "density function.")

Comment: @angryavian No - but you're right about the classification of the question. I was confused by the term "distribution function," but realized it to be synonymous with cumulative distribution function and now the notation makes perfect sense. Thanks for the guiding comment!